# How to convert a matrix of SIFT features into a archive readable by Support Vector Machine?

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, svm, sift

I'm just starting a project using OpenCv to extract SIFT features from multiple images. Then I will make a database for training machine with SVM.

Untill now, I studied [this code](https://github.com/abidrahmank/OpenCV2-Python-Tutorials/blob/master/source/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_sift_intro/py_sift_intro.rst) which is very basic. But i would like to know, how should i proceed to convert the matrix of features into a normalized, readable archive for SVM?

What is the best approach to extract features from hundreds of images? (later objective)

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to use search? Such question have been asked not once, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041355/how-to-use-sift-surf-as-features-for-a-machine-learning-algorithm/20044974#20044974

Answer (score 0):

If you can elaborate more on the specific problem you are trying to solve, it would be easier to answer.

However, I can suggest using the Bag of Words approach of which you can read about here:
http://gilscvblog.wordpress.com/2013/08/23/bag-of-words-models-for-visual-categorization/