# How to get a fixed size SIFT feature vector?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, data-mining, sift, vlfeat

I am trying to obtain feature vectors for N =~ 1300 images in my data set, one of the features I have to implement is shape. So I plan to use SIFT descriptors. However, each image returns different number of keypoints, so I run

```
[F,D] = vl_sift(image);
```

F is of size `4 x N` and D is of size `128 x N` where N is the number of keypoints detected.

However, I want to obtain a single vector of size `128 x 1` that can represent an image as good as possible. I have seen things like clustering and k-means, but I don't have any idea how to do them.

The most basic idea is to get the average of these N vectors of size 128x1, then I have a feature vector. But is taking the average meaningful? Should I do some kind of histogram?

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks !

Comment: you may look this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/36796437/1197132 and ayn further questions are welcomed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually a big research problem.  You are correct, averaging all the descriptors will not be meaningful.  There are several approaches out there for creating a single vector out of a set of local descriptors. One big class of methods is called "bag of features" or "bag of visual words".  The general idea is to cluster local descriptors (e. g. sift) from many images (e. g. using k-means).  Then you take a particular image, figure out which cluster each descriptor from that image belongs to, and create a histogram.  There are different ways of doing the clustering and different ways of creating and normalizing the histogram.

A somewhat different approach is called "Pyramid Match Kernel", which is a way of training an SVM classifier on sets of local descriptors.

So for starters google "bag of features" or "bag of visual words".

Comment: If you are *supposed* to do Bag of Words, then you really should read up on this. Because BoW doesn't work with one 128d feature per image. It works with lots of features per image, which are then *each* converted to "words", which will yield a 1000+ sparse vector per image.

Comment: Exactly. I did this for SIFT and around 1500 keypoints per image, and around 1000 images, I have more than 2m vectors in total. Once I compute the vocabulary with k-means, I hope I'm good. Any ideas on how to obtain this for Color descriptors? The only thing I can think of is the hue histogram, but it results a single vector per image.