# Retreiving similar images from a set of images using SIFT/SURF

Tags: opencv, k-means, feature-extraction, sift, cbir

I am working on SIFT features and 'm using a visual bag-of-words approach to make a vocabulary first and then do the matching. I've found similar questions but didn't find the appropriate answer.
Same question is asked in below link but there is no satisfactory answer, can anyone help me. Thank u in advance.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366944/finding-top-similar-images-from-a-database-using-sift-surf

Answer (score 0):

Sift and Surf Method  are all implemented in lire project and ready to use. Code is very simple if you know the bag of visual word you can modify also.

https://github.com/dermotte/LIRE complete bag of visual word is fully implemented. here is the [lire Demo](http://demo-itec.uni-klu.ac.at/liredemo/) site.

You may look details and implementation of the methods on opencv library [for feature extraction](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_detection/feature_detection.html#feature-detection). After getting visual word you should use information retrieval approaches used in search engines. By the way Lire also include an information retrieval library called [lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/core/). You may stick to lire way until you get the whole idea.